# Webpack - Exporting all functions directly to be used in the browser

Tags: webpack

I am developing a library that I want it to work for node and browser at the same time.

Lets say I have this library file `mylibrary.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  add: function (a, b) {return a + b;},
  sub: function (a, b) {return a - b;}
};
```

I can use it nicely in node application as following `fun.js`:

```js
const mylibrary = require('mylibrary'); // CommonJS style
import {add, sub} from 'mylibrary';     // UMD style

var x = mylibrary.add(1, 2); // method 1
var y = add(1, 2);           // method 2
```

Both methods work fine without issues.

Now I want to be able to use it in the browser in the following way:

```html
<script src="mylibrary.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var x = add(1, 2); // doesn't work! Using mylibrary.add() will work
    var y = sub(1, 2); // but I want to use sub() directly; not mylibrary.sub()
</script>
```

I want to expose `add()` and `sub()` directly in the browser without requiring the user to qualify it with any name (I know it is usally advised to group all functions from a library under a common name to avoid namespace collision; but this is ok in my case).

Currently I am using the following `webpack.config.js` but it exposes `add()` and `sub()` under an object called `mylibrary`. Thus in the browser, the user has to write `mylibrary.add()` which I want to avoid.

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/mylibrary.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'mylibrary.min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'mylibrary' // need to avoid this for the browser
  }
};
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following the webpack [config page](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment), use this configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/mylibrary.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'mylibrary.min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'window'
  }
};
```

The important options to set are **`libraryTarget`** (set to `window`) and **`library`** (to `undefined`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked. Strangely enough, I tried `window`, `this`, and `global` and didn't work before. It might be because I didn't omit `library: 'mylibrary'`.

Comment: I finally found the answer to this 1000$ question, thank you !

Comment: How do we do this to a custom global? F.e., I don't want it to assign all exports to `window`, but to something else like `MyLib` but I want it to create `MyApp` if it doesn't exist, otherwise re-use it (not override it).

Comment: `libraryTarget: 'window'` did it. Thanks